# Android: wait until activity is on top

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, wait

I need to pause program execution until one of my activities comes on top of the activity stack.

This code doesn't work.
How do I attach a handler to a background thread?

```
public void pauseUntilOnTop()
    {
        if(!isTopActivity())
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(runWaitTop);
            worker.start();         

            synchronized(instance) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    // Calling wait() will block this thread until another thread
                    // calls notify() on the object.
                    instance.wait();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity life cycle methods.

The method `onResume` is a good start: it's called when Activity is ready and may receive user actions.

Be carefull that activation lifecycle methods allways have a counterpart for deactivation, e.g. `onPause` for `onResume`, and they may be called more than once.

Btw study topics like `Services`, `AsyncTask` and `Loader` and see if they fit your needs instead of  using low level threading API. Also there's plenty of higher level APIs on `android.os` package to address common Android scenarios.